# Howto install Magento2 Testframework as dev requirement

Tags: magento2, composer, testing, integration-test

until now, I developed my Magento2 Modules in the app/code directory of a running magento2 instance. This is pretty easy and you can run your tests without having much to think about.

after reading this: [Magento 2 as composer dev requirement for extensions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104970/magento-2-as-composer-dev-requirement-for-extensions), I wanted to try a more "clean" approach to develop a Module.

So I started by creating a new Project and pulled in all needed dependencies with composer.

While writing my first integration test i recognized that I'm missing the Testframework classes. For the first step, I just want to have the autocompletion in my IDE.

So my question is: Is there any possibility to install the Magento Integration Test Framework without having to install the whole mage2-base package? I couldn't find a composer package for this. (talking about this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do (still a work in process - much potential for improvement)

https://github.com/davidverholen/magento2-blog

Answer (score 0):

The Magento Test Framework is available in its [own repository](https://github.com/magento/mtf). You can find instructions for using it [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_introduction.html)

Comment: thx, but this is not the Framework used for M2 Integration testing. Updated my question to make it more clear that I'm searching for this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework